# Infoblox BloxOne Security Best Practices

Tags: dns

I'm looking for some guidance regarding security best practices for [Infoblox BloxOne](https://www.infoblox.com/products/bloxone-threat-defense/).

What I'm looking for specifically are recommended security best practices based on experience using the product.

Comment: This is very broad. What kind of "best practice" are you looking for?

Comment: ask the vendor for their best practices